# Autocapitalize TextField in Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, touch, uppercase, capitalize

I need to autocapitalize the first letter in a textfield, every time, when the user is using his iPhone and typing a text in my system.

I am solving this with listeners for now:

```
listeners : {
    scope: this,
    keyup: function(field, e) {
        if (field.getValue().length < 5) {
            field.setValue(field.getValue().substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getValue().substr(1));
        }
    },
    blur: function(field, e) {
        field.setValue(field.getValue().substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + field.getValue().substr(1));
    }
}
```

But I need to show the virtual input keyboard in uppercase too.

Then with this functionality I have the problem partially performed.

I need to know if there is other method automatized in Sencha for this.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the attribute autocapitalize for the textfield

```
autocapitalize="on"
```

Comment: Which, in Sencha Touch, is even to be found in the docs if you search for "capitalize": http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4.0/#!/api/Ext.field.Text-cfg-autoCapitalize

Comment: Yes, but not in ExtJS. I did look it up :)